# Searching for any instance of a whole word in a text column

Tags: r, regex, string

Assuming I have the following

```
text <- c('flight cancelled','coach test') 
searching_for<- c('flight','coach')
```

I'll like to find any instance where a whole word in "searching_for"  is in "text". I used:

```
as.integer(str_detect(searching_for, text))
```

As it stands now it's failing to detect that the word 'flight' is in the text 'flight cancelled'.

Additionally I also want to be able to identify any  instance where a minimum of one word in 'searching_for' is present in 'text.

As an example

```
 searching_for<- c('flight school',' head coach')
```

Should return true in both instances of 'searching_for' as the words 'flight' and 'coach' do exist in 'text' albeit as part of a large phrase.

How can I go about doing this? My actual dataset has over 100k rows..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
text <- c('flight cancelled','coach test') 
searching_for<- c('flight','coach')

+(colSums(sapply(searching_for, grepl, text, fixed = TRUE)) > 0)
flight  coach 
     1      1
```

Comment: What does `fixed=TRUE` do in this context? I can't seem to see anything about it in the docs, and without it, the output looks the same

Comment: @Mark check `?grepl` or `help('grep')` and then look at the `fixed` argument. Notice OP wants to match the string as it. eg `|` will not work if there is `|` in the string to start with.

Comment: Ah! it's an argument of `grepl` . Thank you!!

Comment: @ Onyambu. Thanks for your response. I notice that it doesn't work in the example below  ```text <- c('flight cancelled','coach test') 
searching_for<- c('flight school',' head coach')

+(colSums(sapply(searching_for, grepl, text, fixed = TRUE)) > 0)``` Notice that 'flight' and 'coach' are in text but are not flagged as true.

Comment: @ianaj you said that you want a whole word in searching for.  You will have to ask a different question with that iN MIND. Please note that the example you gave was insufficient for the task you had in mind. you should consider asking the question, giving different lengths for text and searching_for vectors, giving different strings

Comment: @ Onyambu I have edited my original question.

Comment: @ianaj I would encourage you ro ask a new question to attract more interested people. In the new question you can present your main problem. Editing this question changes the whole idea and makes the solutions given to be incorrect/ of no use. Rather leave the question, accept one of the solutions given to close the question and then open a new question

Answer (score 1):

we can use `str_equal`

```r
text <- c('flight cancelled','coach test') 
searching_for<- c('flight','coach')

as.integer(str_equal(text,searching_for))
```

[1] 0 0

Comment: I realised I had an error in my question so I've edited it. Ideally I want to be able to detect any individual word in a string. So that if I flip the code it can work..

Comment: ok the ideal solution for this would be to use `str_equal`

Comment: This is incorrect. OP is not interested in equality per ser but rather to detect that the searching for strings are in the text strings.

Comment: I am not sure of the solution, if we check the answer you provided can be accomplished with str_detect as well, could you please let me know what is the difference

Comment: `str_detect` is vectorized on both the string and pattern on a one to one. hence not suitable to work if the length of both the string and pattern are different or even if they are randomized. eg try `str_detect(rev(text), searching_for)` and you will notice that it returns 0 instead of 1

Comment: thank you @Onyambu, I get it what you mean

Answer (score 1):

```
library(stringr)

str_detect(text, str_flatten(searching_for, "|"))
# TRUE TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `outer` + `grepl` like below

```
> rowSums(outer(searching_for, text, Vectorize(grepl))) > 0
[1] TRUE TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
map_lgl(text, ~ any(str_detect(.x, searching_for))) # [1] TRUE TRUE 
# TRUE is equivalent to 1; ie. TRUE + TRUE = 2, so converting it into an integer most likely isn't necessary
```

Comment: You should loop over the pattern and not the text ie `map_lgl(searching_for, ~any(str_detect(text, fixed(.))))`

Comment: This will be incorrect in the case of `searching_for <- c('flight','coach', 'test', 'not there')`

Comment: Interesting @Onyambu, maybe I'm just half awake, but I read it  the other way  ("'ll like to find any instance where a whole word in "searching_for" is in "text""

Comment: i.e. is any item in `searching for` in `text`? The code you gave does the reverse

Comment: I hadn't heard of fixed, thanks for sharing! :-)

Comment: Sure but you are still looping ove the text instead of the pattern. So unless you edit, this code is not correct

Comment: Thanks @Mark and @Onyambu for this discussion I am learning. I noticed that it does work in this instance ```text <- c('flight cancelled','coach test')  searching_for<- c('flight school',' head coach')   ```. The reason why I need it this way is that my searching_for column is very ad hoc and in some instances it has 'flight' or 'coach' but in other instances it has 'flight' and a host of other words but really want I want is that any instance of a minimum of one word in searching_for being present in text to be TRUE.